# Connectiong adsl router/modem and router with bridgemode

Tags: networking, routing, router, bridge, modem

I have one adsl modem/router which is not "top" of the line and it lack allot of options which I need.  I was able to acquire one Cisco router recently which has all options that I need ( like DMZ, VPN, port forwarding, etc). I'm interested, if I connect the old modem/router to  new Cisco router using bridge mode, will I be able to use all the features on the Cisco? For instance,  the old router is lacking of port forward options.   Does this mean that I will not be able to use port forwarding on Cisco router either or, since I will be using bridge mode, this will not affect Cisco router and it will work as the modem is in him?

thank you

Comment: What protocols is the ADSL running? This will work like a charm if your ISP is using PPPoE, and if you have access to your credentials (username and password). If you have to use PPPoA or IP over ATM, then your ZyXEL modem will keep control of the IP and you won't be able to do much, unless you are able to configure 1-to-1 NAT or set up a bridge in a "creative" way, that is, manually configuring the IP address on the Cisco and hoping that the ZyXEL modem keeps relaying the packets correctly even if you manually set private IPs and routing rules on the ADSL and Ethernet interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be yes. If the Zyxel is configued as a modem only then the Linksys should work.  Your ISP could require the use of their modem as a modem/router so that will be a question for them.

Comment: hi,  the new router is linksys WRT610N.   The modem/router is some kind of old Zyxel. My ISP has tendency to use some strange modem/routers. But anyway, basically my new router will work like it has it's own modem in it if I  use bridge mode

Comment: @ZvonkoTelefonko: Yes, that's right. In bridge mode, the modem basically makes itself invisible and only converts between ADSL and Ethernet. You can setup things like port forwarding on the router and it should work.